# Audio device on iOS 4?

Tags: audio, ios, microphone

I was looking for /dev/dsp or /dev/audio through terminal but I couldn't find either of the two. Is there any audio device on iOS 4 (specifically iPhone 4) for input or output?

Comment: This technical question is probably more appropriate for stackoverflow.com than on apple.stackexchange.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Questions about development are off-topic for this site. You might try www.stackoverflow.com. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only exposed API to use the audio hardware under iOS is the RemoteIO Audio Unit API.  The driver for the audio input/output hardware does not seem to be exposed via a *nix device on Mac OS X, or in its iDevice derivatives.